# What is the more elegant way of finding combinations in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I came up with this algorithm to find triplets of `pairs` (I call them `trairs`), the criteria is that all 3 elements (coins), and only the 3, must be present in all 3 `pairs`.

However, it is probably possible to solve the same problem in a more elegant way. For instance, I am indexing all the loops, which makes it look extra complicated. Also, there is a `break` there that makes me uncomfortable!

The input data is `pairs`, it is a `list` of `str`:
Eg. `pairs = ['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','DASH/USD','BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC']`

The wanted output is a `list` of `list` of strings:
Eg. `trair = [['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','ETH/BTC]]`

```
def find_trairs(exchange):
    ''' Find possible triplets of pairs (trairs) that can be traded for unbalance.

    Example of trairs:
    'ETC/BTC' 'ETC/ETH' 'ETH/BTC'
    'BCH/BTC' 'BCH/EUR' 'BTC/EUR'

    '''
    exchange_pairs = exchange.symbols #loads all pairs from the exchange.
    pairs = list(filter(lambda x: not '.d' in x, exchange_pairs)) #filters off 
    #the darkpool pairs.

    pair = ['', '', '']
    coin = ['', '', '']
    trair = []

    #Semi-optimized loop to look for triplece of pairs.
    #Example:['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/EUR', 'BTC/EUR']
    for i in range(len(pairs)-3):
        #not all coins are 3 digits long, we must find the slash that separetes
        #each coin in order to have a robust algorithm.
        slash_position = pairs[i].find('/') 
        coin[0] = pairs[i][0:slash_position]
        coin[1] = pairs[i][slash_position+1:]
        for j in range(i+1, len(pairs)-2):
            if (coin[0] in pairs[j]):
                slash_position = pairs[j].find('/') 
                coin[2] = pairs[j][slash_position+1:]
                for k in range(j+1, len(pairs)-1):
                    if coin[1] in pairs[k] and coin[2] in pairs[k]:
                        trair.append([pairs[i], pairs[j], pairs[k]])
                        break

    return trair
```

Any hints or comments?

Comment: Have you looked into `itertools`? There seems to be a function within the package (`itertools.combinations()`) that does what you want.

Comment: Maybe another useful optimization is to use the `.split("/")` command instead of your (still correct) way of separating at the "/" sign. For example
`coin[0], coin[1] = pairs[i].split("/")`

Answer (score 3):

Use itertools permutations, with filtering the results, and elimination of duplicates:

```
import itertools

currency_pairs = ['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'DASH/USD', 'BTC/USDT', 'ETH/BTC']
set_triplets = set()
for triplet in itertools.permutations(currency_pairs, 3):
    c1, c2 = triplet[0].split('/')
    if (c1 in triplet[1] or c1 in triplet[2]) and (c2 in triplet[1] or c2 in triplet[2]):
        set_triplets.add(tuple(sorted(triplet)))
for triplet in set_triplets:
    print(triplet)
```

#### output:

```
('BCH/ETH', 'BTC/USDT', 'ETH/BTC') 
('BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'BTC/USDT')
('BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'ETH/BTC')
```

*Please note that the ordering of the currency pairs in a triplet is lexicographically ascending, do not expect the first pair to always be the link between the two others.*

Comment: This appears to miss a required constraint. For each pair in the triple, the two coins must appear in the other two pairs.

Comment: This doesn't seem like what OP wanted; you might want to re-read the question. The title is a little misleading.

Comment: I don't think your output matches your code, i.e., the members of each triplet are not sorted. This could also give wrong answers if 'BCH/ETH' and 'ETH/BCH' are both in the input list (not sure if that's a possibility).

Comment: nono, the output matches the code. Maybe there will be duplicates if both 'BCH/ETH' and 'ETH/BCH' are in the input data; I have not verified.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I missed the sorting (did the output change since yesterday?). But now your first two outputs seem to be incorrect, i.e. they don’t form a linked set of three currencies.

Comment: No, the output has not changed. If you stare at it a bit closely, you will see that the three pairs are linked - they may not be in the order you expect though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but I don’t see how your first and second triplets meet the criteria that “all 3 elements (coins), and only the 3, must be present in all 3 pairs” or make a set of three coin pairs that can be traded for arbitrage. They each include 4 coins, and form a chain from BCH to USDT but no link back again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
coins = set('/'.join(pairs).split('/'))
```

to get a set of all possible coins on the exchange. Then you can get all possible subsets of len 3 of that using `itertools.combinations` with

```
triples = combinations(coins, 3)
```

You can get your "trairs" by taking the combinations of len 2 from your triples.

```
trairs = [{frozenset(pair) for pair in combinations(triple, 2)}
          for triple in triples]
```

The result is a list of 3-item sets where each item is a frozenset representing a coin pair.

---

The exchange may not support all possible pairs directly. If so, you can add an additional filter step to remove the invalid "trairs".

```
pairset = set(frozenset(pair.split('/')) for pair in pairs)
trairs = [trair for trair in trairs if trair <= pairset]
```

The `<=` checks if trair is a subset of pairset.

---

The list of sets of frozensets matches the structure of the problem better so it may suffice for your needs, but it's not exactly the output form specified.

You could convert the frozensets back to strings and the triples to lists using

```
[['/'.join(pair) for pair in trair] for trair in trairs]]
```

Sets are effectively unordered, but it's not clear from the question if this matters, since buying e.g. `BTC/ETH` is the same as selling `ETH/BTC` etc. and it's not clear what use other orderings of the same triple are. So you could instead leave the triples as sets and use the alphabetized pairings like this.

```
[{'/'.join(sorted(pair)) for pair in trair} for trair in trairs]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that uses mostly functionality from the standard library:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations, chain

raw_pairs = ['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'DASH/USD', 'BTC/USDT', 'ETH/BTC']

def parse_pair(raw_pair):
    return raw_pair.split('/')

def is_trair(trair_candidate):
    # assuming that all currencies appear twice means we have a trair
    currency_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(trair_candidate))
    return set(currency_counts.values()) == {2}

pairs = map(parse_pair, raw_pairs)

trair_candidates = combinations(pairs, r=3)

# filter the actual trairs from all trair_candidates
trairs = filter(is_trair, trair_candidates)

print(list(trairs))
```

Will give:

> [(['BCH', 'BTC'], ['BCH', 'ETH'], ['ETH', 'BTC'])]

Comment: That is more in line with what I was looking for =) I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

**Efficient approach**

This will search your input list for valid triplets very quickly. Hopefully it's also fairly clear and simple. But it does normalize the order of the pairs (i.e., puts each pair in alphabetical order). Let me know if that's a problem.

```
pairs = ['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','DASH/USD','BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC']
# make a dict of all alphabetically higher partners for each symbol
pair_dict = {}
for pair_str in pairs:
    p0, p1 = sorted(pair_str.split('/'))
    # create sets if needed, then record this pair
    pair_dict.setdefault(p0, set())
    pair_dict.setdefault(p1, set())
    pair_dict[p0].add(p1)

# process the dict, finding all valid triplets of pairs
triplets = list()
for p0 in pair_dict:
    p0_pairs = pair_dict[p0]
    for p1 in p0_pairs:
        p1_pairs = pair_dict[p1]
        for p2 in p1_pairs:
            if p2 in p0_pairs:
                # there's a chain from p0 to p1 to p2 to p0;
                # add them to the list of triplets
                triplets.append((p0, p1, p2))
final = [[p0+'/'+p1, p1+'/'+p2, p2+'/'+p0] for p0, p1, p2 in triplets]
print(final)
# [['BCH/BTC', 'BTC/ETH', 'ETH/BCH']]
```

I used sets instead of lists in `pair_dict`, because they're faster to search through and they eliminate any duplicates. Also, `for p0 in pair_dict` is the same as `for p0 in pair_dict.keys()`, and `for p0, p1, p2 in triplets` means "take each element from `triplets` and split it into the `p0`, `p1` and `p1` variables."

**Simpler approach**

If you're looking for something simpler (albeit less efficient), you could try the code below.

Note that this relies on a couple of interesting things. 1. If you sort the coins within each pair and also sort the pairs within each triplet, then you are guaranteed that each valid triplet will look like ['a/b', 'a/c', 'b/c'], where a, b and c are the different coins, in alphabetical order. 2. If you feed a sorted list to `itertools.combinations()`, the triplets it produces [will also be sorted](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

So the code below sorts within each pair, then sorts the list of pairs, then uses `itertools.combinations()` to get sorted triplets. Then it checks whether any of those triplets match the required pattern.

```
import itertools
# added another pair to make it more interesting
pairs = ['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','DASH/USD','BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC','USDT/ETH']
pairs_normalized = sorted(sorted(pair.split('/')) for pair in pairs)
triplets = [
    (p1, p2, p3) 
    for p1, p2, p3 in itertools.combinations(pairs_normalized, 3)
    # look for ['a/b', 'a/c', 'b/c'] pattern
    if p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[1] == p3[0] and p2[1] == p3[1]
]
output = [['/'.join(p) for p in triplet] for triplet in triplets]
print(output)
# [['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'BTC/ETH'], ['BTC/ETH', 'BTC/USDT', 'ETH/USDT']]
```

Comment: Putting them in alphabetical order is definitely not a problem. The pairs ought to be re-sorted later on for different analysis.

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi Good to know. Since it looks like you prefer the filtered-combinations approach, I added a simple and correct version of that too.

Comment: Thanks, man =). It is true that the code is taking a rather long time to run with the filtered-combination approach. There are other parts of the code that deserve priority for now, but it is in my backlog to look at this part again. I'll definitely consider your efficient approach.

Answer (score 2):

List Comprehensions and i'm sure that this can be improved, you can try something like this:

```
>>> pairs = ['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','DASH/USD','BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC']
# ['BCH/BTC','BCH/ETH','DASH/USD','BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC']
```

get the coins:

```
>>> coins = [j for i in pairs for j in i.split('/')]
# ['BCH', 'BTC', 'BCH', 'ETH', 'DASH', 'USD', 'BTC', 'USDT', 'ETH', 'BTC']
```

get the coins that appears more than one time,and save in set, to avoid duplicates

```
>>> coins = {coin for coin in coins if coins.count(coin)>1}
# {'BCH', 'BTC', 'ETH'}
```

find the trairs where only this coins appears:

```
>>>  trairs = [i for i in pairs for j in coins if i.split('/')[0] and i.split('/')[1] in j]
# ['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'ETH/BTC']
```

using filter:

```
>>> trairs = filter(lambda x: (x.split('/')[0] and x.split('/')[1]) in coins, pairs)
# ['BCH/BTC', 'BCH/ETH', 'ETH/BTC']
```

**New update with itertools:**

```
>>> coins = {j for j in set('/'.join(pairs).split('/')) if '/'.join(pairs).split('/').count(j)>1}
# {'BCH', 'BTC', 'ETH'}
```

then

```
>>> trairs = list(itertools.combinations(coins, 2))
# [('ETH', 'BCH'), ('ETH', 'BTC'), ('BCH', 'BTC')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

The current implementation is:

```
import ccxt
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations, chain

def parse_pair(raw_pair):
    return raw_pair.split('/')

def is_trair(trair_candidate):
    # assuming that all currencies appear twice means we have a trair
    currency_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(trair_candidate))
    return set(currency_counts.values()) == {2}

def format_trairs(u_trair):
    '''fortmat the trairs to the correct format. List of List of str.

    input:
        u_trair: trairs in the format List of Tuples of list of strings.
        eg.:[(['ABT','BTC'],['ABT',ETH'],['ETH','BTC])]
    output:
        trair: trais in the format List of list of str.
        ['ABT/BTC', 'ABT/ETH', 'ETH/BTC']   
    '''
    trair= [] #stores the trairs in the correct format.
    for one_trair in u_trair:
        t_trair = [] #temporary trair. 
        for one_pair in one_trair:
            t_trair.append(one_pair[0]+'/'+one_pair[1])
        trair.append(t_trair)
    return trair

exchange = ccxt.kucoin()
market = exchange.load_markets()
exchange_pairs = exchange.symbols

raw_pairs = list(filter(lambda x: not '.d' in x, exchange_pairs))

pairs = map(parse_pair, raw_pairs)
trair_candidates = combinations(pairs, r=3)
#filter the actual trairs from all trair_candidates
u_trair = list(filter(is_trair,trair_candidates)) #unformated trairs.
trair = format_trairs(u_trair) #formats the trairs to list of list os strings.
```